# Change a certain digit in variable bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have defined variable of certain apt package:

`VAR_0=$(echo $(apt-cache policy <some apt package> | grep Candidate:) | grep -oP 'Candidate:\ \K.*').`

In `echo $VAR_0` it outputs for example: `2.7.4`.

What should I do to get one variable where only the 3rd digit gets +1, and one variable where only the 2nd digital gets +1?

In the case where `VAR_0 = 2.7.4` I want to get `VAR_1 = 2.7.5` and `VAR_2 = 2.8.4`. Its an
assumption that `VAR_0` always have only 3 digits in format as above.

I tried to get $VAR_0 into a text file and edit it via `sed` command, but maths operations do not any affect since its a string I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the string comma. `read` will be perfect here.

```
IFS=. read -r major minor patch <<<"$VAR_0"
```

> get one variable where only the 3rd digit gets +1

```
one_variable="$major.$minor.$((patch + 1))"
```

> one variable where only the 2nd digital gets +1?

```
one_variable2="$major.$((minor + 1)).$patch"
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck. `echo $(...) | grep` looks odd. Just execute the stuff `apt | grep | grep`, no echo.